Where is the GitHub Copilot Autocompletions Panel in Visual Studio 2022?
VS Code has an Autocompletions Panel for GitHub Copilot, allowing you to see multiple options for auto-completing your code generated from Copilot and select one from the list.
Where is the Visual Studio 2022 equivalent of this panel?  I don't see it in the Copilot dropdown, nor do I find any options in the Settings section:

Is this feature simply not available in the full Visual Studio IDE?

GitHub Copilot's Autocompletions Panel like in VS Code is currently not available in Visual Studio 2022. The integration in Visual Studio focuses more on inline suggestions and as of now there isn't an equivalent multi-option panel like in VS Code.You can keep an eye on updates from GitHub Copilot as this feature might be added in future releases.

Thanks @Shruti1603.  It's interesting that VS Code would actually be more full-featured in certain areas than the full Visual Studio.  As a workaround for now, I found that I can ask the Copilot chat directly for multiple options for a problem, i.e., "List multiple ways of doing xxx".
